# Find$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + 2x + 4}\,dx$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2 + 2x + 4}\,dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + 2x + 4}\,dx$$

and

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^2 + 2x + 4}\,dx$$

I find it really difficult.

Much appreciate it if anyone can solve this for me thanks.

Comment: Yes I know the basic of residues theorem and other complex analysis  but I am stuck how to start this.

Comment: Hint use $e^{ix} =i sin(x)+cos(x)$ to do both integrals at once.

Comment: @Mike: please unaccept my answer and, if you wish, accept Aaron Maroja's answer. It seems that I have included too much detail while trying to show that Jan Eerland's result-only answer has an error.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Consider the function $$f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2  +2z  +4}$$ Notice that $f(z)$ has poles at $-1 \pm i \sqrt 3$. Choose one root and take the path $C_R$ to be a semi-circunference of radius $R > 2$.

Use the Residue Theorem, to find the real and imaginary parts of your function $f(z)$ as $R \to \infty$.

Comment: I don't get why is radius R >2?

Comment: To use The Residue Theorem, you need a path that has a pole inside its region. What is $\sqrt {1^2 + (\sqrt 3)^2}$?

Comment: alright, thanks allots!

Comment: You're most welcome! I'm glad you could make it.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I have one last question, shouldn't cos(x)=[exp(ix)+exp(-ix)]/2? according to  Euler formula?

Comment: How would parametrize this path? $C_R$.

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit of detail:

Let $\gamma_1$ be the contour $[-R,R]$ and $\gamma_2$ be the contour $Re^{i[0,\pi]}$ as $R\to\infty$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+2x+4}
+i\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+2x+4}\\[6pt]
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{ix}\,\mathrm{d}x}{(x+1)^2+3}\tag{1}\\[6pt]
&=\frac1{2i\sqrt3}\int_{\gamma_1\cup\gamma_2}\left(\frac1{z+1-i\sqrt3}-\frac1{z+1+i\sqrt3}\right)e^{iz}\,\mathrm{d}z\\
&-\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{e^{iz}\,\mathrm{d}z}{(z+1)^2+3}\tag{2}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{2\pi i}{2i\sqrt3}\operatorname*{Res}_{z=-1+i\sqrt3}\left(\frac{e^{iz}}{z-(-1+i\sqrt3)}\right)\tag{3}\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}e^{i(-1+i\sqrt3)}\tag{4}\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}e^{-\sqrt3}(\cos(1)-i\sin(1))\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: [Euler's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$(2)$: the integral over the line is the limit of the difference of two contour integrals
$(3)$: [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) and
$$\small\left|\int_{\gamma_2}\frac{e^{iz}\,\mathrm{d}z}{(z+1)^2+3}\right| \le2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{-R\sin(\theta)}}{(R-1)^2}R\,\mathrm{d}\theta \le2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{e^{-2R\theta/\pi}}{(R-1)^2}R\,\mathrm{d}\theta\le\frac{\pi}{(R-1)^2}$$
$(4)$: evaluate the residue
$(5)$: Euler's Formula

---

Equating the real and imaginary parts above, we get
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cos(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+2x+4}=\frac\pi{\sqrt3}e^{-\sqrt3}\cos(1)\tag{6}
$$
and
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+2x+4}=-\frac\pi{\sqrt3}e^{-\sqrt3}\sin(1)\tag{7}
$$

Comment: I have worked it out and got the same answer as yours thanks

Comment: A bit of detail?

Comment: @AaronMaroja: Since I was getting a different answer than Jan Eerland, I put the whole computation. I'm sorry if it seems like too much detail.

Comment: @robjohn It's just that you as a moderator should know that this question is not "qualified" according to the MSE terms, that is, it's off-topic. And as far as I was explained these types of question should receive answers, if at all received, according to what has been presented. I don't know, sometimes I don't get the terms here. The OP didn't know how to begin and apparently managed to get the hint right. I don't see why you did this. But it's alright.

Comment: @AaronMaroja: If the OP will unaccept my answer, I will delete it. I've had things go funny when an accepted answer is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It gave us:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\cos(x)}{x^2 + 2x + 4}\,dx=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{3}}\pi \cos(1)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

And

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x^2 + 2x + 4}\,dx=\frac{e^{-\sqrt{3}}\pi \sin(1)}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: What gave those?

Comment: @robjohn the answers on the integral!

Comment: I believe the sign is wrong on the integral with the sine.